# Installing / Using Microsoft R Client on Mac OS

Tags: macos, microsoft-r

I have just started a job where I need to get upto speed on the Microsoft R.

I want to understand some of the parallel functions such as rxSummary / rxGetInfo / rx* .... other functions.

I want to use these functions at home.   But I only have Mac OS computers.

Is it possible to get this functionality using Mac OS....?

I have installed Micosoft R Open...but this seems to provide only improved Maths Libraries.

I have noticed that Microsoft client is available for Unix / Windows OS.

But hopefully, I want to avoid using a virtual scenario.

Any other options...?

Comment: Only Linux and Windows are supported. If you don't want to run a VM on your local machine, you could spin up a [Data Science Virtual Machine](https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/microsoft-ads.standard-data-science-vm) on Azure.

Comment: Ubuntu DSVM link: https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/microsoft-ads.linux-data-science-vm-ubuntu